# List of lists into a Python Rich table

Tags: python, rich

Given the below, how can i get the animal, age and gender into each of the table cells please?  Currently all the data ends up in one cell.  Thanks

```
from rich.console import Console
from rich.table import Table

list = [['Cat', '7', 'Female'],
        ['Dog', '0.5', 'Male'],
        ['Guinea Pig', '5', 'Male']]

table1 = Table(show_header=True, header_style='bold')
table1.add_column('Animal')
table1.add_column('Age')
table1.add_column('Gender')

for row in zip(*list):
    table1.add_row(' '.join(row))

console.print(table1)
```

Comment: Where/what is the definition of a ?rich? `Table`? Is it an external package?

Comment: Sorry my mistake - missed the import.

Comment: before printing table with console, you should define console as `console = Console()`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just use `*` to unpack the tuple and it should work fine.

```
for row in zip(*list):
    table1.add_row(*row)
```

Note that

```
table1.add_row(*('Cat', 'Dog', 'Guinea Pig'))
```

is equivalent to

```
table1.add_row('Cat', 'Dog', 'Guinea Pig')
```

While previously your approach was equivalent to

```
table1.add_row('Cat Dog Guinea Pig')
```

Comment: very helpful. also, in some cases, you may need to map elements with str, like *table.add_row(*(map(str, imd_table[index])))*