# How do I zip a list of lists into a Python Rich table with headers and rows

Tags: python, iteration, nested-lists, list-manipulation

I'm trying to extract data from a Google Sheet of indefinite size and use it to build a table to display in the terminal, but I'm evidently doing something wrong. I'm trying out the method and syntax described in [this post (List of lists into a Python Rich table)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65216850/list-of-lists-into-a-python-rich-table) and getting the equivalent of:

| Animal | Age | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | Dog | Guinea Pig |
| 7 | 0.5 | 5 |
| Female | Male | Male |

Instead of the desired:

| Animal | Age | Gender |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Cat | 7 | Female |
| Dog | 0.5 | Male |
| Guinea Pig | 5 | Male |

Could anyone clarify? Apologies if it's something silly; I'm quite new to Python as you can probably tell.

My actual code, in case you can spot the fault, is:

```
from rich.console import Console
from rich.table import Table

records = test_records.get_all_values()
table = Table(title="Test Records")

for heading in records[0]:
    table.add_column(f"{heading}")

for row in zip(*records[1::1]):
    table.add_row(*row)

console = Console()
console.print(table)
```

Like the OP in that question, I have a list of lists, stored as the variable `records` as referenced in the above code. My list contains my headers, but I'm handling those separately in the code above as you can see. Perhaps that's where I'm going wrong?

Example of list data:

```
 records = [
     ['Date', 'Time', 'Username', 'Value (A)', 'Value (B)', 'Message'],
     ['07.04.22', '09:00', 'John', '3.00', '3.00', 'Some string data.'],
     ['08.04.22', '10:00', 'Jane', '3.00', '5.00', 'Some string data.']
 ]
```

Comment: fwiw, `records[1::1]` is the same as `records[1:]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that the `zip` function isn't needed. Remove it and it works.

```py
from rich.console import Console
from rich.table import Table

records = test_records.get_all_values()
table = Table(title="Test Records")

for heading in records[0]:
    table.add_column(f"{heading}")

for row in records[1::1]:
    table.add_row(*row)

console = Console()
console.print(table)
```

Your data is already formatted in a horizontal way, not vertical.